# Symfony2 / Doctrine2 - Associating entities to certain connection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have two MySQL connections set in my Symfony config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default: __VARIABLES
            dealer: __VARIABLES
```

I know I can retrieve objects from certain connection by:
`$this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('dealer');`

My question is - is there a way to set connection to certain entity, so the `doctrine:schema:update` syncing is done only in the scope of the set connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you can specify in entity manager section entity manager's responsibility. You can use "dir" option for this purpose. You have to disable auto_mapping options and tell Doctrine which entities are related to which entity manager. For example:

```
doctrine:
   dbal:
       (...)

   orm:
       auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%        
       default_entity_manager:   default
       entity_managers:
           default:
               connection:       default
               mappings:                    
                   CompanySomeBundle:
                       dir: Entity/BaseEntity/

            secondem:
                connection:      second_connection
                mappings:                 
                    CompanySomeBundle:
                       dir: Entity/AdditionalEntity/
```

In that every entity in BaseEntity dir belongs to "default" em, and these entities from AdditionalEntity dir belong to "secondem" entity manager.